# Accidentally used the rip feature (v) but I need to make my model the same amount of vertices to join as shapes

Tags: modeling

I create faces for mods for PES 2020 and to export the face from blender and into the game the model needs to be the same amount of vertices as when it was imported.

When I edit the face I export my work and then import it back to the original model and join as shapes.

Unfortunately I pressed v instead of c when modelling and I didn't notice until after exporting that it had created a new vertical.

Does anyone have any way at fixing it? I can't find the difference because I pressed V, right clicked and the pressed C as normal. So it didn't actually rip the model but just created a new vertical.

Comment: Try doing a "Merge by distance" operation, that should remove the rip.

Comment: Also, you have to be in "Vertex select" mode to be able to merge by distance